# xPath - Extracting a contents of a href from an anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath

I am having difficulty extracting the contents of a href from an anchor tag with xPaths. I want to extract the contents of the href only, not the text contained within the anchor elements.

This is what I've come up with so far but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
//a/@href[contains("@", 'mailto')]/text()
```

I also tried:

```
//a/href[contains("@", 'mailto')]/text()
```

Anyone have any suggestions, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask for `@href` instead of `text()` and check for the `@href` attribute to contain `mailto`:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'mailto')]/@href
```

Comment: Seems to be working great thanks, only issue I have is this is pulling multiple copies of the href into one cell. When inspecting the html there is only one instance so I am not sure why this would be looping and causing duplication.

Comment: Its actually a carriage return that I am getting within each cell.